# OWASP ZAP disable POST requests (out of scope)

Tags: owasp, zap

How can I exclude POST requests in OWASP ZAP? It is spamming a lot of forms and contact forms and therefore interrupting the normal operations of a website. Can I exclude this with a regex or is there an option build in?

Comment: You mean, it is sending POST requests to domains not in scope? Or to pages within the domain that are out of scope?

Comment: Have you read the manual? How do 'contexts' or 'scope' not meet your requirements?

Comment: It is sending POST request in scope, but I would like to exclude POST requests in general. Is that possible?

Comment: Because this is a question on the configuration for a specific program, it belongs on StackOverflow. They even have a `zap` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Active Scan dialog check the 'Show advanced options' box.
You will then see more tabs - select the 'Input Vectors' ta and then deselect the 'POST Data' target. For help on this dialog click the help button - the help is also online here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsAdvascan

You can also create different policies via the Scan Policy Manager :)

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)